# Call FastRPC as XMLHttpRequest encoded in base64 in C#

Tags: c#, xml, http, base64, rpc

I am trying get altitude from the API provided by Czech service (mapy.cz) using C#. Here is JS example in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vwf0d7uy/3/).

```
var coords = SMap.Coords.fromWGS84(15, 50);
coords.getAltitude().then(altitudeResponse);
```

The content type of the request is: **application/x-base64-frpc**

So I the solution would be to create FastRPC call in C#, encode it by base64 and send it to the server. I searched how to create such call, but with no luck.

Does any one has suggestion how to solve this?

Thank you very much,

**EDIT:**
I tried to compare payload of two requests:

```
yhECAWgLZ2V0QWx0aXR1ZGVYAVgCGEC4AgplXC1AGM91aIktS0lAOAEQ
yhECAWgLZ2V0QWx0aXR1ZGVYAVgCGEC4Agrlci1AGAsmNM7mQElAOAEQ
```

And the difference should be the parameters for the call. Which mean, that another possible solution would be to construct this request:

yhECAWgLZ2V0QWx0aXR1ZGVYAVgCGEC4Ag + [parameters] + lAOAEQ

**EDIT2:**

Another hint could be [here](https://ondras.zarovi.cz/slides/2012/seznamden/examples/frpc.html).

It generates their FRPC call and print the byte sequence.

Comment: I must be close since I got the word altitude : byte[] response1 = Convert.FromBase64String("yhECAWgLZ2V0QWx0aXR1ZGVYAVgCGEC4AgplXC1AGM91aIktS0lAOAEQ");
            string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response1);

Comment: It is not wierd. It is because the returned altitude is there represented as float or int. It is not encoded as characters.

Comment: I did not say wierd!!!

Comment: I force server to send response in XML format and now I am getting readable data. Last challenge... create that request payload.

Answer (score 2):

Encoding / decoding this payload is implemented in
https://github.com/seznam/JAK/blob/master/util/frpc.js

The encoded data can be displayed in the console calling 
`console.log(JAK.FRPC.parse(JAK.Base64.atob("your-payload")));`. It can be tested easily when pasting this code to any [example](https://api.mapy.cz/view?page=examples) as they can be tweaked directly in JSFiddle.